# google-api drive rest How to test file/folder permissions in development environment

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm trying to test altering permissions on folders and files in Google drive using the rest API and a service account.  I can't tell from the documentation whether there are any limitations in the development environment, but I've tried adding a user through the developers console, and altering permissions on files and folders that would affect the newly added user.  I've tried adjusting permissions on files and folders in a way that should affect all users, didn't work.  I'm consistently getting a 401 Unauthorized response.  This is what's leading me to think there may be limitations in the dev environment as I'm able to do other tasks through the service account (upload file, copy file, download file), but I'm *not* able to rename a file, nor create one.

My question: Are there any limitations to testing permissions in Google's development environment while using a service account?  If not, any ideas on what the problem might be?

Here's an example of the code I'm using, but I've tried PUT/Update, too:

```
String uri = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/myfileID/permissions?access_token=";
```

.....

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)
WebRequest.Create(uri + "?access_token=" + myjwt.access_token);
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/json";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append(" { ");
sb.Append(" \"role\": \"reader\", ");
sb.Append(" \"type\": \"user\", ");
sb.Append(" \"value\": \"myuser@mydomain.com\" ");
sb.Append(" } ");
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());
writer.Write(sb.ToString());
writer.Close();
```

...........